# How many cards should be picked up?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

In a standard deck of $52$ cards, what is the minimum number of cards you need to pick up, in order to guarantee that there is a suit with at least $3$ cards?

Shouldn't I pick $10$ cards? Please explain in detail.

Also, what would be the minimum number of cards to be drawn out such that a suit has at most $3$ cards in the LEFT-UP pile?

Comment: Do you know what the pigeonhole principle is?

Comment: Yeah, I do know it.

Comment: __Hint:__ Your pigeonholes are the 4 suits, your pigeons are the cards. You want 3 pigeons in a pigeonhole.

Comment: Ok, I got it. In the worst possible case, when each suite has equal probability distribution, each suite will have 2 cards each and thus the last ninth card must be drawn out.

Comment: Probability has nothing to do with it, as you are asking for a guarantee.  You could ask for the expected number to draw before you get three of the same suit, but that would be a different question.  It would involve probabilities.

Comment: @Ross, What would be the answer to the second question?
Should it be 10?

Comment: If the LEFT-UP pile is the cards not drawn, you should draw 49.  The last four cards could be all the same suit otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Turn the question around: what’s the **most** cards you can pick up **without** getting $3$ in one suit? There are $4$ suits, so if you have at most $2$ cards in each of them, you can have at most $4\cdot2=8$ cards. The moment you pick a ninth card, you must have at least one suit with at least $3$ cards in it.